# Position in Member Declaration Breaks Code?

Tags: c++, line

A while ago I asked a question on why the following code did not work:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<Tile_Base*>>> map_tile; // This is located in Map object. See below.
int t_x, t_y;
t_x = t_y = 200;
map_tiles.begin(); // clear(), resize() and every other function still causes problems
```

The thing is, is that it should have worked, yet Visual Studios 2012 throws an exception when the resize function is called. The exception pointed to this piece of code:

```
*_Pnext != 0; *_Pnext = (*_Pnext)->_Mynextiter)
```

located in xutility. It said that there was an violating on access to reading the memory. I thought maybe somehow I lost access to the member along the way? (Using VS' watch I saw the memory was not corrupted)

So, I fiddled around with the code and tried to figure out what could possibly be going wrong, and after awhile I moved the map_tiles object down to the bottom of the list, and it worked:

```
// WORKS
class Map {
    std::vector<Tile_Base*> spawn_tiles;
    // map tile specific
    bool Is_Valid(int,int);
    std::string name;
    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<Tile_Base*> > > map_tiles;
public:
// ...
}
// DOESN'T WORK
class Map {
    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<Tile_Base*> > > map_tiles;
    std::vector<Tile_Base*> spawn_tiles;
    // map tile specific
    bool Is_Valid(int,int);
    std::string name;

public:

// ...
}
```

Any help pointing out what went wrong? I can't come up with any reasonable explanation.

Comment: "the following code" at the top of the post doesn't compile or make sense. Please correct it.

Comment: I did it in the manner of "It doesn't matter if it works or not because the question doesn't relate to its functionality, it is only an example." But I fixed it anyways.

Comment: Sounds to me like you are reading outside of valid memory. This will be undefined, so moving elements in the structure around will alter its behaviour. Unfortunately, I doubt very much that you are actually showing us the code that is causing the problem...

Comment: The trick here is to isolate (and simplify) the code that is causing the problem, and then debug that.

Comment: What does the callstack look like when the exception is thrown? When moving a member around in memory fixes a bug like this it suggests you have corruption, likely causes are object slicing or use of memset/memcpy.

Comment: Does your `vector<std::vector<Tile_Base*> >(t_y/32)` have an element at position `t_y/32` ? The element that is copied in during the resize operation.

Comment: Well, it's whenever I call any function from map_tiles. I guess I'll just have to comment things out until map_tiles works when placed at top.

Comment: Break the resize up like this: `std::vector<std::vector<Tile_Base*> > init(t_y/32); map_tiles.resize(t_x / 32, init);` (the extra vector created matches what you are actually doing but might help to determine where the problem is)

Comment: If it's easily reproduced, set a break point on the resize line, perform the repro and when you get to the breakpoint in the debugger, select the "Callstack" to see where you're being invoked from and then select the "Locals" tab and expand "this". Look for obvious signs of corruption. If nothing stands out, you can always press F11 and step thru the next part of the code.

Comment: Mario, no, that sets the size of the vector, so, if t_y were 64, it should have a vector with 2 empty vectors of tile base pointers.

Comment: Kfstone, the program throws an exception before I even reach the break point set on the resize. Anyways, if the function were erase() or begin() I would still get the exception. EDIT: I can step into it from an instruction before-hand. Anyways, for the clear() function, going inside the "this->_Orphan_all()" line, it still throws an exception at (I don't know how to view callstack): 
*_Pnext != 0; *_Pnext = (*_Pnext)->_Mynextiter)

Comment: That indicates something has overwritten one of the vector's internal state, are you taking the address of the vectors somewhere? The following would produce similar problems: `std::vector<int> f; f.resize(64); memset(&f, 0, sizeof(int * 64));` instead of `std::vector<int> f; f.resize(64); memset(&f[0], 0, sizeof(int * 64));` because `&f` takes the address of the vector object, not the array data that f may own.

Comment: No, this is the first time in the program that the vectors are even being touched, and they never get resized again in the rest of the program. When I look at the contents using Watch, I can see that the members are not corrupted and they are all set to what the vector should be, that is, size 0. I'll probably figure it out later, though. I thought it might be because of some member I could have added to the class, but I had not touched the properties of the class from the time it worked to the time it broke. :\

Comment: Also, I do not use memcpy nor do I slice any objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `vector<T>` comprises two discrete sets of data: the internal state and the array of Ts. The internal state - capacity, size, pointer - is separate from the array. The issue you're describing is normally caused by something overwriting the *vector object*, i.e the internal state. To track this down easily you could use a container class:

```
typedef std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<Tile_Base*> > > maptiles_t;

class CMapTiles
{
    unsigned int m_guard;
    maptiles_t m_tiles;
    enum { Guard = 0xdeadbeef };
public:
    CMapTiles() : m_guard(Guard), m_tiles() {}
    ~CMapTiles() { assert(m_guard == Guard); }

    void Check()
    {
#if defined(DEBUG)
        if (m_guard != Guard)
            DebugBreak();
#endif
    }

    void Resize(size_t x, size_t y)
    {
        Check();
        auto init = std::vector<std::vector<Tile_Base*> >(y/32);
        m_tiles.resize(m_x / 32, init);
        Check();
    }

    const maptiles_t& tiles() const { Check(); return m_tiles; }
    maptiles_t& tiles() { Check(); return m_tiles; }
};
```

And instead of using `std::vector<...> map_tiles` have `CMapTiles map_tiles`, and then when you want to get at the vector, `map_tiles.tiles()`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Alright, well, I guess that works, though it is a side-step I guess it is the best solution I can be offered. Thanks.

Comment: You don't accept it if it wasn't the help you need, that will reduce its exposure :) I realize it was a long shot but it was easier to present this way than in a comment

Comment: I'll post a better solution when I get the exact answer; for now I am on my own.

Though, when I tried your solution and used the Check function, the comparison between the enum and m_guard failed.

Comment: Ah - now what you can do is run it in the debugger, set a breakpoint in the CMapTiles constructor, and then set a data watch on the m_guard member so that the debugger will tell you where it is being overwritten from. (Debug > Break points)

Comment: I'm sorry, by failed I mean that m_guard is still equal to the enum.